# Customizing the JMSPaymentCoreBundle form in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, paypal

I've integrated the bundles `JMSPaymentCoreBundle` and its plugin, the `JMSPaymentPaypalBundle`. However, the form given by the first bundle forces the user to select which payment method he/she wishes to use. In my case, I do not have multiple options, only Paypal. Sadly, the user still has to click on a radio button to confirm he wishes to use Paypal before being redirected to Paypal's site. I would like to remove this step from the process.

This is the form I use:

```
$form = $this->getFormFactory()->create('jms_choose_payment_method', null, array(
            'amount'   => $orderPrice,
            'currency' => 'CAD',
            'default_method' => 'payment_paypal', // Optional
            'predefined_data' => array(
                'paypal_express_checkout' => array(
                    'return_url' => $this->router->generate('paiement_complete', array(
                        'id' =>$order->getId()
                    ), true),
                    'cancel_url' => $this->router->generate('paiement_annule', array(), true)
                ),
            ),
        ));
```

Is there any way to modify this form to remove the choice, or do I need to implement a new form?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can bypass the payment method choose if you want to, and proceed directly to express checkout (or the method you want) directly.

Instead of showing and receiving the form data in an action similar to this:

```
public function detailsAction(Order $order)
{
    // Your form

    if ('POST' === $this->request->getMethod())
    {
        $form->bindRequest($this->request);

        if ($form->isValid())
        {
            $this->ppc->createPaymentInstruction($instruction = $form->getData());

            $extendedData = $instruction->getExtendedData();

            $extendedData->set(
                'checkout_params', array(
                    'L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0' => 'My cool article',
                    'L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_DESC0' => 'this is a description for my article',
                )
            );

            $order->setPaymentInstruction($instruction);
            $this->em->persist($order);
            $this->em->flush($order);

            return new RedirectResponse($this->router->generate('payment_frontpage'));
         }
      }
}
```

You can directly construct the payment instruction and proceed to Paypal in the action:

```
/**
 * Paypal Express Checkout
 *
 * @Route("/{orderNumber}/checkout", name="payment_checkout")
 * @Template
 */
public function checkoutAction(Order $order)
{
    $em = $this->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager');
    $router = $this->get('router');

    // Create the extended data object
    $extendedData = new ExtendedData();

    // Complete payment return URL
    $extendedData->set('return_url',
        $router->generate('payment_complete', array(
            'orderNumber' => $order->getOrderNumber(),
        ), true)
    );

    // Cancel payment return URL
    $extendedData->set('cancel_url',
        $router->generate('payment_cancel', array(
            'orderNumber' => $order->getOrderNumber(),
        ), true)
    );

    // Checkout parameters
    $checkout_params = $this->generateCheckoutParameters($order);
    $this->get('logger')->info(print_r($checkout_params, 1));

    // Add checkout information to the exended data
    $extendedData->set('checkout_params', $checkout_params);

    // Create the payment instruction object
    $instruction = new PaymentInstruction(
        $order->getAmount(), 'EUR', 'paypal_express_checkout', $extendedData
    );

    // Validate and persist the payment instruction
    $this->get('payment.plugin_controller')->createPaymentInstruction($instruction);

    // Update the order object
    $order->setPaymentInstruction($instruction);
    $em->persist($order);
    $em->flush($order);

    // Continue with payment
    return new RedirectResponse($router->generate('payment_complete', array(
        'orderNumber' => $order->getOrderNumber(),
    )));
}
```

__

```
protected function generateCheckoutParameters(Order $order)
{
    // Checkout parameters
    $checkout_params = array();

    // Include items data in the order
    foreach ($order->getItems() as $in=>$item)
    {
        $checkout_params = array_merge(
            $checkout_params,
            array(
                sprintf('L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME%d', $in)   => $item->getName(),
                sprintf('L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_DESC%d', $in)   => $item->getDescription(),
                sprintf('L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT%d', $in)    => $item->getPrice(),
                sprintf('L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY%d', $in)    => 1,
            )
        );
    }

    // Include payments data in the order
    $checkout_params = array_merge(
        $checkout_params,
        array(
            'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_DESC'     => "Order #".$order->getOrderNumber(),
            'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_INVNUM'   => $order->getOrderNumber(),
        )
    );

    return $checkout_params;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I simply wanted to point out that I did need to change the line 
    `$em->flush();`
to
    `$em->flush($order);`

Comment: Quick question. If I put a discount on my order, there seem to be a problem with the checkout parameters. Is there a specific parameter I should use in this case?